Problem uploading image and relating to object
Good afternoon everyone, I need to upload a photo and relate it to a record. This record is for an individual object that I created, but it is limited to a few objects, as mentioned in this material,
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm
I've even tried attaching related files, but it gives me the same error when I do it through a flow. Is there any way to solve this?


The Individual object is not supported, but the IndividualApplication object is.  From the documentation for LinkedEntityId:

... Identifier, Image, IndividualApplication, Invoice, InvoiceLine,
...

